# String to date converter issue in js

Tags: javascript

My local machine in EST timezone.

I'm trying to convert date string to date object in js but getting an day before from date string in date object.

`new Date('2020-04-03')` for this i'm getting `Thu Apr 02 2020 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` this output.

`new Date('2020/04/03')` for this i'm getting `Fri Apr 03 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` this output.

```js
console.log(new Date('2020-04-03'))
console.log(new Date('2020/04/03'))
```

I don't know what is the difference between these can anyone explain that?

How i fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the two date parsings give you different results is because it's triggering two different date handling modes.

In one case, `2020-04-03`, it's treating the date as an simplified version of [ISO 8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) format, for which JavaScript creates a date in the UTC time zone if no time zone is specified.

The second date, `2020/04/03`, is not in an officially supported format, so JavaScript falls back to an implementation-specific parsing of the date, so it may not even be consistent across browsers. In that case, it's choosing to use your local time zone.

[The MDN article on `Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) offers a detailed explanation of how date parsing works in the JavaScript standard and how non-standard behaviors exist among browsers in some cases.

In short, it's a good idea to stick with ISO 8601 dates whenever possible, not only because JavaScript handles them in a consistent way, but they're also easily sorted, and they're widely supported across many programming systems.

Answer (score 0):

Try `new Date('2020-04-03 00:00:00')`

Comment: Thanks this is working fine. Can you explain what is the difference between ```new Date('2020/04/03')``` ```Fri Apr 03 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)``` and ```new Date('2020-04-03 00:00:00')``` ```Fri Apr 03 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the date string is parsed in UTC timezone. When you output a date, by default it converts it to your local timezone set by your browser.

To solve, you can enter your date as the UTC equivalent, or simply do as the others have stated here and include the timezone in your date string

```
let date = new Date('2020-04-03 EST');
```